# How to detect if memory was allocated? (Linked lists)

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, malloc

I want to create a function that adds an element to the end of a linked list. It also has to return 0 if the element was added successfully, or a 1 if memory could not allocated/saved to for the element.

The question is, how do I know if the memory was allocated successfully or if the element was added successfully? This is the code:

```
int push_back(pos_t *head, int new_value) {
    pos_t *temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    pos_t *temp1 = (pos_t *)malloc(sizeof(pos_t));
    temp1->data = new_value;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    temp = temp1;
}
```

Comment: `temp=temp1;` --> `temp->next = temp1;` ?

Comment: Is `head == NULL`  possible?  It would be useful to see how the link-list is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code

```
if (temp1 == NULL) { return 1; }
```

because `malloc` is defined to either return a pointer to the allocated memory, or

- if the size is zero, return NULL.
- on error, return NULL.

You can control that you don't request a size of zero, so if you used a positive size, and `malloc` returned NULL, you can deduce an error occurred.

Many systems have "manuals" installed.  If you are using a Linux system, the command "man malloc" will pull up the manual page for `malloc`.  If you are working on a Windows system, a web search for [the manual for `malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) will give you enough detail to handle the details.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to add a `return 0;` too, and the locations of both code additions are left for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The function has a shortcoming: it cannot be used to allocate the first node in the list, ie if the list is empty.

The prototype should be changed to

```
int push_back(pos_t **headp, int new_value);
```

passing the address of the list pointer instead of its value.

Testing for `malloc()` failure is simple: juts compare the returned pointer to `NULL` or `0`.

Here is the corresponding code:

```
int push_back(pos_t **headp, int new_value) {
    pos_t *temp = *headp;
    pos_t *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(pos_t));
    if (temp1 == NULL) {   // allocation failure
        return 1;
    }
    temp1->data = new_value;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if (temp == NULL) {      // empty list
        *headp = temp1;
    } else {
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = temp1;  // append node to the end of the list
    }
    return 0;
}
```